# CSS background gradient not working in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using the following CSS to try to get a vertical background gradient to display in most browsers.

It works fine in Firefox but is not displaying in Chrome.

You can see where I'm trying to apply the gradient in the footer section of http://blog.bmxboss.com

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%, #111111 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#222222), color-stop(100%,#111111)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#111111 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#111111 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#111111 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222 0%,#111111 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#111111',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

How can I make this work in Chrome?

Comment: There's no problem with that CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/C4fnY/2/

Comment: Your code works fine in all browsers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [a tool I made](https://www.assembla.com/code/danny-beckett/subversion/nodes/12/CSS%20Gradient%20maker) to generate CSS gradients, this is the CSS for a gradient from `#222222` to `#111111`, with support for all browsers:

```
background: #222222;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%, #111111 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#222222), color-stop(100%,#111111));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#111111 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#111111 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#111111 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222 0%,#111111 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#111111',GradientType=0 );
```

Here is [a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4fnY/1/).

Comment: It looks all black in chrome for me

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9dWCD.png Albeit with a very subtle gradient... the `test` text in the `<div>` is true black. So by being able to see that, you know the colour behind it is lighter than black.

Comment: Got ya. I guess I didn't notice that. It would be a lot more demonstrative of the capability that you are trying to show off if you used a far lighter color for one of the start or stop colors...

Comment: @DannyBeckett What is the diference between your code and the code in the question? :D

Comment: @Sbml Just noticed that too. Just tested the OP's original code and it also works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/C4fnY/2/

Comment: awesome i think it was just my internet connection  its primarily satellite based and i couldnt get it to show up for like 10 minutes in chrome i see it now though and i think your right about lightning it up to see the effects better  =) im just kinda hacking away like a madman seeing where the design goes  lol i need the slider set up and a logo to visualize how i want the overall layout to come together  im gonna keep playing with gradients and shadows thanks for the responses guys =)

Comment: yah for me i wasnt even seeing the black at all it was just appearing blank showing the wood background.

Comment: @user2592186 Remember to click the ✓ icon next to my answer to accept it - you will gain +2 rep.

Comment: thanks for the answer and insight danny i wouldnt have thought to click that  =)